# LED in op-amp`s feedback loop shines dimly. How to eliminate this?

Tags: operational-amplifier, led, led-driver, single-supply-op-amp

I am working on my project's visual indicator part.

Everything woks as expected, but LED shines dimly when connected in feedback loop and with no control signal. Shining is barely visible, but it is still there. I want it to be connected in feedback loop because this way I get LED response I need (I use low control voltage). Is it possible to lower op-amps output voltage a little bit using this configuration?

[image]

Comment: Is the LM358 a rail-to-rail opamp? Or what is the minimum voltage it can output?

Comment: The LM358 includes Ground within both the input and output range.  Problem is most likely input-offset voltage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The control voltage may be at 0 volts but, the LM358 has significant input offset voltage errors. Let's say that the "effective" input on the non-inverting terminal is 2 mV (due to offset errors). This means that the op-amp uses negative feedback via the LED to reproduce 2 mV on the inverting input. This in turn means that the current through the 1 kΩ resistor is 2 μA and, that current also flows through the LED.

The bottom line is that many modern LEDs will faintly glow with 2 μA flowing.

> *How to eliminate this?*

Experiment with a moderate valued resistor across the LED. Maybe 100 kΩ will do the job; maybe a bit less will work better.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is to put a resistor in parallel with the LED.  You will have to experiment to find the highest-possible value resistor that kills the illumination.

Another possibility is to add a high-value resistor from the op-amp (-) pin to the incoming supply rail.

The other way to fix this is to use an op-amp with lower input-offset voltage.

Answer (score 1):

LM358 has no trouble operating its inputs near 0V, so it's not an input common mode range problem, unless you're not really using LM358.

All opamps have a little bit of offset voltage. In your circuit's case, if the offset voltage is the "right" polarity, it will be applied to the output which means a non-zero current will flow through the LED even if input voltage is zero.

In addition if your control voltage source has high output impedance, the small input current of the opamp can add some more offset.

The simplest solution is to wire a resistor in parallel with the LED.

First measure voltage across the 1k resistor when the LED should be off. Suppose it's 1mV, this means there is 1µA through the LED. At this current its Vf should be around 1-1.3V so... pick a resistor that will take this 1µA current at this voltage, say 1Megohm, and wire it across the LED. Adjust the numbers according to what you measure on the resistor.

Comment: Thanks. Straight to the point!!!!